# Idiomatic phrase

Tags: idioms

"I'm not one to forget, you know"
This is from a song lyrics, and It means I  always can't let the past go and remember what happened in mind.

I wonder can we use this idiomatic structure in other way?
"He is not a person to learn"
I want to say he don't learn anything from the mistake and keep repeating the mistake.
But I worry about other might misunderstood the meaning into he is not a good example for me to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much any verb, active or passive, can be used with the "not one to" pattern.

> He's not one to take that sitting down.
>
> He's not one to complain.
>
> He's not one to learn new things quickly.
>
> He's not one to spend much thought on such a thing.
>
> He's not one to listen.
>
> He's not one to try new foods.
>
> He's not one to drink flavored coffees.
>
> He's not one to sing on key.

A complement is needed if the verb is "to be":

> He's not one to be easily duped.
>
> He's not one to be trusted.